# Rotating double X Axis Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

using my last answer ([Plotly line, changing colour to NaN segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996352/plotly-line-changing-colour-to-nan-segments)) I would like to ask something new.

Following the code below I plotted 2 xAxis where ARE shared between themselves to assure when moving one xAxis the other one is moving too. But I need to rotate xAxis labels from both xAxis because when my data is more than 12 entries the labels overlaps each other and rotating may avoid this. If I add rotation to update_layout to xaxis1 or xaxis2 just repetition label is rotating, date ticks are not rotating.

BTW, is there any way to remove the dividers between repetitions/dates from xAxis?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import itertools as it
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import column_or_1d


class MyLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):
    def fit(self, y):
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        self.classes_ = pd.Series(y).unique()
        return self


df = pd.DataFrame([1, None, None, 4, 6, None, 2, 1], columns=["y"])
df["x"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df["rank"] = [
    "baseline",
    "beginner",
    "beginner",
    "apprentice",
    "apprentice",
    "expert",
    "expert",
    "expert",
]
df["x_dates"] = [
    "2022-01-01",
    "2022-01-04",
    "2022-01-07",
    "2022-01-10",
    "2022-01-13",
    "2022-01-16",
    "2022-01-19",
    "2022-01-22",
]

le = MyLabelEncoder()

le.fit(df["rank"])

rank = le.transform(df["rank"]) + 1

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# generate color list
df.loc[df["y"].isna(), "line_color"] = "red"
df.loc[df["y"].isna(), "line_type"] = "dash"


df.loc[df["y"].notna(), "line_color"] = "black"
df.loc[df["y"].notna(), "line_type"] = "solid"

df["y"] = df["y"].interpolate(method="pad")

# create coordinate  pairs
x_pairs = it.pairwise(df["x"])
x_dates = it.pairwise(df["x_dates"])
y_pairs = it.pairwise(df["y"])


for x_data, x_date, y, line_color, line_type in zip(
    x_pairs,
    x_dates,
    y_pairs,
    df["line_color"].values,
    df["line_type"].values,
):
    # create trace
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[x_date, x_data],
            y=y,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(color=line_color, dash=line_type),
            showlegend=False,
        ),
        secondary_y=True,
    )

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[df["x_dates"], df["x"]],
        y=rank,
        showlegend=False,
        text=rank,
        # marker_color="rgb(158,202,225)",
        # marker_line_color="black",
        # marker_line_width=1.5,
        # opacity=0.6,
    ),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.update_layout(
    {
        "xaxis1": {
            "title_text": "Repetition/Date",
        },
        "yaxis": {
            "title_text": "placeholder",
            "showgrid": False,
            "anchor": "x",
            "domain": [0.0, 1.0],
            "side": "right",
        },
        "yaxis2": {
            "title_text": "data",
            "anchor": "x",
            "overlaying": "y",
            "side": "left",
        },
        "xaxis2": {
            "tickvals": np.arange(
                0,
                np.max(df["x"]) + 1,
                1,
            ),
        },
    }
)

fig.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This vertical line appears when the x-axis is a categorical variable and set to multi-index. As far as I know, I don't think there is a function to hide this, so there is no choice but to handle the x-axis by concatenating the x-axis strings instead of specifying the list.

Comment: Hmmm @r-beginners that would be a nice workaround I will try later, thanks!